# cannot import name 'pipline' from 'transformers' (unknown location)

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, huggingface-transformers

I am getting this error when trying following code in the jupyter-lab:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
```

Amazingly, if I copy that line of code in a `code_test.py` file, and execute it using `python3 code_test.py`(both in the terminal and jupyter-lab itself) everything will work fine.

I am using jupyter-lab and which is configured to use a virtual-env(the one containing transformers module).

I have searched for similar problems, but none of proposed solutions worked(such as reinstalling the **transformers** module).

**Edited**:

Output of `sys.path` in jupyter-lab:

```py
['/Users/{my_username}/{path_to_my_project}/code',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/Users/{my_username}/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/{my_username}/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/{{my_username}/.ipython']
```

Output of sys.path in `code_test.py`:

```
['/Users/{my_username}/{path_to_my_project}/code',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
'/Users/{my_username}/{path_to_my_project}/code/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: when you type `python3 code.py` I'm guessing that it isn't using the virtual-env, you might double check the virtual-env to ensure it has `transformers`

Comment: @jonyfries before typing that command, I have typed ```source env/bin/activate``` which assure I am in the right venv. and I am sure the venv has **transformers**.

Comment: What is the output of `sys.path` in jupyter-lab and in code.py? Please add the output directly to your question.

Comment: @cronoik I added those outputs.

Comment: Jupyter-lab isn't using your virtual environment as you can see there (`'/Users/{my_username}/{path_to_my_project}/code/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages'` is missing). You can check the location of transformers with `transformers.__file__`. I haven't worked with jupyterlab but it seems like that activating your virtual environment is not enough. You need to register it: `python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv` (haven't tested it just copied it from [here](https://www.zainrizvi.io/blog/jupyter-notebooks-best-practices-use-virtual-environments/)).

Comment: @cronoik It worked. Thanks alot for your response. Would you please write ur answer so that others can benefit too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when you face such an issue that an import is working in one environment (script code_test.py) but not in the other (jupyter-lab), you need to compare the search path for modules with `sys.path` and the location of the module with `MODULE.__file__` (`transformers.__file__` in this case).

When you compare the outputs of `sys.path` of both environments you will notice that `'/Users/{my_username}/{path_to_my_project}/code/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages'` is only listed in one and this is exactly the location where the transformers module is loaded from (output of `transformers.__file__`). That means jupyter-lab is not using your virtual environment.

All you need to do is to register your environment for jupyter-lab with:

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=env
```

and jupyter-lab will now allow you to select the environment as kernels.